# Chequear si el valor de una variable es igual a un valor almacenado en una tupla o array

Tags: python

ando intentando simplificar una confirmación, la cual pide que respondas con Si o No.

Me preguntaba si habia alguna forma de meter las distintas variantes de la palabra "No" en una tupla y hacer que la variable "Respuesta" chequee que es igual a uno de los valores de la tupla

```
negativo=("NO", "No", "no", "nO")

respuesta=input(Responda con Si o No)

if respuesta==negativo:
   print("La respuesta ha sido: No")
```

algo asi sería, el tema es que a mi no me funciona de esa forma pero sé que hay a pesar de no encontrarla

Comment: `if respuesta.lower() == "no":`

Comment: `if respuesta in negativo:`

Comment: Aparte de lo que mencionan los compañeros de encima, no te funciona porque la cadena dentro del input debe ser una string. `respuesta=input("Responda con Si o No")`

Comment: Sisi, el codigo que puse en la pregunta lo hice en el momento y es un error que muchas veces suelo tener, en el codigo original que tengo lo tengo como un string, Gracias igualmente, lo pude resolver gracias a las respuestas <3